# read yml file in a Symfony action

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, yaml

i have a short amount of configuration data (not enough to use a table in the database) and i wanted to keep it in a YAML file. Since Symfony uses this format in a lot of parts of the libray i guess is not hard to read an *.yml file and have this information in an action.

My YAML file looks like this: is a hierarchy menu definition

```
#menu-config.yml
.basicUser:
    menu: menu1
        menu: submenu1.1
            link: link1
                url: url1.com
        menu: submenu1.2
        link: link2
            url: url2.com
        link: link3
            url: url3.com
    menu: menu2
        menu: submenu2.1
            link: link4
                url: link4.com
.admin
...
```

what i want to get is a php array with the hierarchy of menus, submenus and links

I tried this:

```
$myYaml = sfYaml::load('<path-to-my-yaml-file>');
```

but when i `echo` , `print_r` or `var_dump`  it in a template only show "1". :S
I'm sure that i load a file because the function `is_file('path-to-my-yaml-file');` returns true.

So, have anyone had good results with that? Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your yaml file valid ? No tab, etc ..

Did you tried with an other yaml file, like [this one](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/config/config/settings.yml) and see what the php array is?

I used to manually load a yaml in an actions, I do:

```php
$database = sfYaml::load(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/databases.yml');
$param    = $database['all']['doctrine']['param'];
```

And it workds perfectly. I think, if the load return only `1` it means it failed or sth is wrong with the file.

Comment: oh! the yml i was loading had no a valid format. I tried to load the `databases.yml` document and generates the php array correctly. Thanks